# AWS EKS Fargate logging on cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I have create an eks cluster on fargate. I want to send container logs to cloudwatch. for that i have use this guideline([eks-fargate-logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-logging.html). I want to create cloudwatch stream as namespace-pod-name. how can we do this ??

Answer (score 0):

Need to use older cloudwatch plugins. dont use cloudwatch_logs plugin.[cloudwatch plugin](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-logs-for-fluent-bit)